# How to create a drop-down /select in Codeigniter with multiple identical key values?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, dropdownbox

In HTML this is perfectly legal:

```
 <select name='val'>
     <option value='0'>Wrong Answer</option>
     <option value='0'>Also a wrong Answer</option>
     <option value='1'>Correct Answer</option>
     <option value='1'>Also a correct Answer</option>
     <option value='1'>Another correct Answer</option>
</select>
```

How does the array look to be passed to form_dropdown('val',$array) in Codeigniter in this case? 
Is this possible at all?

Comment: It's not possible without extending the form helper. Alternatively you could give them different values and check which are correct/incorrect in the controller, or build the select manually from your custom array format.

Answer (score 0):

Give **key=>value** paired array as parameter to form_dropdown()
syntax of form_drop() function is:

echo form_dropdown('name_of_dropdown',$key_value_pair_array);

here is my Working code:
student is array which contains student ID as key and student name as value now pass this array to form_dropdown()

```
$student["101"]="student1";
$student["102"]="student2";
$student["103"]="student3";
$student["104"]="student4";
$student["105"]="student5"; I

echo form_dropdown('student',$student);
```

Comment: these don't have *multiple identical key values* as per my example.